# how do you send params to template

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to setup a simple messaging system between two users, x and y.

```
x views domain.com/user/:_id (where_id is user y)
x clicks message

x goes to domain.com/message/:_id (where _id is for the message thread if exists in messageCollection - query where to:user y's id and from:user x's id)
else
x goes to domain.com/message/newMessage
```

the newMessage is where I would like to pass user y's id, but preferable without a url param.
Is this possible through iron-router? Also, would this be the best design to do something like a private message in meteor.

Thanks

Comment: Question is if its possible send params without attaching to url. the the messaging problem is a design question (not looking for a code just opinion), not every question requires code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a global variable for this. For example, before you route the user to the newMessage-page, set `newMessageReceiverId = 'user_y_id'`. I don't think Iron-Router has support for this ( I can't see the reason you want to avoid it).